# I do not understand the output of bind -P in bash

Tags: bash

I dont understand the output of the `bind -P` command.
What does the characters mean -

```
"\C-g", "\C-x\C-g", "\e\C-g 
 "\e-", "\e0", "\e1", "\e2", "\e3", ...
```

Kindly explain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- `"\C-g"` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> - Abort
- `"\C-x\C-g"` - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> - Abort
- `"\e\C-g` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> - Abort
- `"\e-"` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> - Begin a negative number for a count argument
- `"\e0"` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> - A digit for a count argument
- `"\e1"` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> - Same
- `"\e2"` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> - Same
- `"\e3"` - <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> - Same

See [`man readline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) for more information

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) for bash, the `-P` switch does this:

```
List current Readline function names and bindings.
```

Readline is a [library integrated with bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Interaction) (usually) as well. Thus, the bindings in the `-P` switch are the *keyboard combinations* necessary to run the associated readline function. So, for example:

```
... snip ...
beginning-of-line can be found on "\eOH", "\e[H".
call-last-kbd-macro is not bound to any keys
capitalize-word is not bound to any keys
character-search is not bound to any keys
character-search-backward is not bound to any keys
clear-screen is not bound to any keys
complete can be found on "\C-i".
... snip ...
```

This shows that the function `complete` is bound to the key combo `"\C-i"` which is shorthand for control-i. The `\C` and so forth chars are the meta keys displayed as control codes.